# Realm in IntentService - thread created crash

Tags: android, realm

I have a Realm thread that is causing a crash, and I'm not sure why this isn't allowed, or how to get around it.  Here's some sample code of what's going on:

```
public class UploadPostService extends IntentService {

public UploadPostService() {
    super("UploadPostService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    String uniqueCode = intent.getStringExtra("uniqueCode");

    OurApi api = OurApi.build(this, Application.apiRoot);

    final Realm r = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

    final RealmResults<Post> thePosts = r.where(Post.class)
            .equalTo("post.code", uniqueCode)
            .findAll();

    if (thePosts != null && thePosts.size() > 0) {
         for (final Post post : thePosts) {
            api.uploadMedia(paramsToUpload, new Callback<Post>() {
                @Override
                public void success(Post postResponse, Response response) {
                    if (post.isValid()) {
                        r.beginTransaction();
                        post.setAField(blah); // CRASHES HERE
                        r.commitTransaction();
                    }
                }
         }
  etc...
```

After the API finishes with the Retrofit call, It crashes on the setting of any field on the "Post" object with the exception:

```
"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created."
```

I'm curious what the cleanest solution to this should be?  Assuming the callback is on a different thread than the IntentService one.. I need to update the actual Post, and it's not letting me;  I've tried creating separate Realm instances, but it doesn't let me update the Post, since it's not (apparently) queried from the same instance.

This is crucial to our code, so I'm a bit stumped.  Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because IntentService runs on background thread but your api callback tries to run on the UI thread, which means it's on a different thread than where the Realm instance to which your RealmResults belongs to was opened.

Also, you were going to write into the Realm on the UI thread anyways, which is discouraged.

Use synchronous API call in `IntentService`. In Retrofit, it is `call.execute()`.

I also hope you are closing the Realm instance in a finally block!